# Lua iterating string for whitespace

Tags: string, lua, whitespace

```
whiteSpace = 0
foo = "foo bar"

for i = 1, #foo do
    if (string.sub(foo, i, i) == "%") then
        whiteSpace = whiteSpace + 1
    end
end

print(whiteSpace)
```

I'm trying to loop through this string in each character, check if it is whitespace. If the character is whitespace, I want to increment the whiteSpace variable and output it at the end. But for some reason when I execute it, it always returns 0, even though there is clearly whitespace within the foo string.

I've used `"%"`, `"%s"` and `""` with no avail. Pretty clueless right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
whiteSpace = 0
foo = "foo bar"

for i = 1, #foo do
    if (string.sub(foo, i, i) == " ") then
        whiteSpace = whiteSpace + 1
    end
end

print(whiteSpace)
```

with pattern matching

```
a, whiteSpace = string.gsub("foo bar","%s","")
print(whiteSpace)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
whiteSpace = 0
foo = "foo bar"
foo = string.gsub(foo, "%s", " ")

for i = 1, #foo do
    if (string.sub(foo, i, i) == " ") then
        whiteSpace = whiteSpace + 1
    end
end

print(whiteSpace)
```